# Filtering association rules by consequents (rhs)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on association rules using different shopping baskets and want to see just the rules which produce a specific consequent. My rules are defined in the code below

```
rules = association_rules(fi, metric="confidence", min_threshold=0.7)
rules['antecendent_len']=rules['antecedents'].apply(lambda x: len(x))
rules = rules[(rules['antecendent_len'] >=2)]
```

I'm specifically looking for "Limes" in the RHS which I can see in the list of rules but when I try the following I get a blank df as my return:

```
rules = rules[(rules['consequents'] == "Limes")]
```

Anyone know how I can filter?

Comment: what does your data look like?

Comment: @JoshFriedlander underlying data is a sparse matrix with individual Items as column headers and shopping basket id's as the rows. The output of my association rules is a table with headers

antecedents consequents antecedent support consequent support support confidence lift leverage conviction antecendent_len